# Firebase (Web) can't get orderByChild to work

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I know that there are 1,000 answers out there to this question, which is partially why I'm so confused by the fact that I can't get it to work.

I can't get the orderByChild query / filter to work. I've looked at at least 25 tutorials, guides, and articles online that explain it and they all seem to say to do exactly what I'm doing:

```js
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref();
var filterExperience = dbRef.child("Users").orderByChild('trade_general').equalTo('Construction');

filterExperience.on('child_added', snap => {

  // Just trying to figure out if anything's even happening
  console.log("Test" + snap.val());    

  // Set Card ID    
  $('#cand-card').attr('id', 'cand-card' + snap.key);

  // Set Name
  $('#fullname').attr('id', 'fullname' + snap.key);
            $('#fullname' + snap.key).text(snap.child("Personal").child("first_name").val() + " " + snap.child("Personal").child("last_name").val());

// And so on...
```

And, for the record, firebase is all set up properly. I have the snippet at the bottom of my html page and I've been reading / writing records with no issue.

My database looks like this:

```js
Users
|
|--KYQ0L5TStcZM1rgVpte
    |
    |-Account
    |-Availability
    |-Education
    |-Location
    |-Work_History
      |
      |-Recent_Job_1
        |
        |-employer_name: "abc company"
        |-job_position: "concrete finisher"
        |-trade_general: "Construction"
```

The result that I'm getting is: absolutely nothing. Nothing in the console from that test that I run right after the 'snap'. Nothing on the page.

Comment: There is no property named `trade_general` in your JSON.

Comment: My bad. It's there in Firebase, just forgot to copy it here. I had been trying for a long time to get queries to work with numerical startAt & endAt's and had just given up on that to see if I could get something (seemingly) simpler to work; like equalTo. So "job_years" was stuck in my head as the relevant piece of information for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Database queries consider each *child* under the location you query and then take the child+conditions that you specify. So if the path is fixed you can do:

```
dbRef.child("Users")
     .orderByChild('Work_History/Recent_Job_1/trade_general')
     .equalTo('Construction')
```

So this consider the `Work_History/Recent_Job_1/trade_general` for each user and filters based on that.

But most likely `Recent_Job_1` is a dynamic path. In that case you're trying to query for a property at a nested, dynamic path, which is not possible in the query model of the Firebase Database. Firebase's indexes are essentially single-value maps and this type of query wouldn't work with those.

You'll have to find a different data structure to allow the query you want.

One way to do that would be to hold the latest `trade_general` value as a direct property under each user. That would allow you to filter by the latest job's trade_general value.

Alternatively you can set up a different data structure that maps `trade_general` values to users and jobs. E.g.

```
UsersJobTradeGenerals
  KYQ0L5TStcZM1rgVpte
    Construction
      Recent_Job_1: true
      Recent_Job_4: true
    OtherTradeGeneral
      Recent_Job_2: true
      Recent_Job_3: true
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks so much for your help. Query now works (recent_job_1 will ultimately be dynamically generated, but is static in development so I can at least get queries figured out) Now I'll look into re-structuring my data as you mentioned.