# How do you query firebase data with a value lower in the JSON tree than the data I'm trying to display?

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What I'm trying to do is take the values for stat and sort them in a specific order using the query method and display it in a tableview. The problem is that I'm trying to get the sort value for the query but I cant go any lower than the team level because the value for timestamp is random, the child key values are always static though. I am using a for statement to get the stat value but doing the same for the sort value would involve nesting another observer and doing that in a for statement would probably be bad because it would make a lot of requests. Here is my code for this as well.

```
func dataObserver() {
    ref.child("LeagueDatabase").child(league).child(age).child(team).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
            self.playerStatsList.append(snap.value(forKey: "stat") as! String)
            self.playerDataTable.reloadData()
        }
        print(self.playerStatsList)
    })
}
```

JSON

```
{
"LeagueDatabase": {
    "-user created league names-": {
        "-user created team names-": {
            "-timestamp to seconds-": {
                "stat": "-random user content-",
                "sort": "-timeSince1970 as double-",
            }
        }
    }
}  
 }
```

Comment: While you can query on lower-level properties, the path to that property must be known at "compile time". This means you cannot query on a dynamically generated lower-level property. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234521/firebase-web-cant-get-orderbychild-to-work/41246692#41246692 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41848856/how-to-read-query-data-from-one-userid-firebase-android/41851064#41851064

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen even if the child elements are constant? Is there a method that just selects all of the children similar to snapshot.children like i did in my for statement